# How do I create a Client Logos section in admin menu?

Tags: plugins, gallery

My company is hosting an event where 50 clients will be at an exhibition.

I want to create an Ehibitors section with separate admin menu. I want to be able to add Exhibits with custom fields for exhibitor_id, exhibitor_logo_img, exhibitor_title and exhibitor_bio.

What is the best way to do this? I dont want to end up with 50 exhibits in one post/page. Ideally, I want 50 separate and sortable pages within a admin menu section.

Any ideas? Hope this makes sense, WordPress noob.

Cheers,

Comment: you could use custom post types, which is a bit overkill for such a list, or take a look at PODS - http://podsframework.org/. This is exactly the type of datastorage you need here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would probably best be solved with a custom post type for the Exhibit.

That will give you a new section in the admin-area with posts/pages for each exhibitor.
That way you can for example use:

- Post thumbnail as "exhibitor_logo_img"
- The post title as "exhibitor_title"
- The content area as "exhibitor_bio"
- And if you need the "exhibitor_id" separate from the content, that could be done with a custom field named "exhibitor_id".

Have a look in the WordPress codex for info on how to setup a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types).

Or if you prefer a more graphical way of doing it, you can also do the same with a plugin. There are several plugins that handles the setup. Such as "[Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)".

Comment: Thanks, I have been having a go with CPT for a while. It should do what i want it to along with the AdvancedCustomFields plugin and CodepressAdminColumns. Im having issues adding a ACF logo image. Its probably related to the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, I think a Custom Post Type is not really the thing you are looking for here.

I would create a Custom Data Table with the [PODS Framework](http://podsframework.org/) where you can add exactly the fieldds needed, and use them in your templates. You don't need all the post functionality here, like post_date, excerpt etc.

Comment: You are probably right that Custom Post Types might be a little overkill. Good tip about the PODS Framework, I had totally forgotten about that!

Comment: Thanks, for reminding me about PODS. I might give this a go since im having some minor problems with CPT.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is enough for you, but in WP does exists the possibility to add and manage custom profile fields, that are in the Users pages, in a very simple way.

Here is the code I use in one of my sites:

```
/************** User Info */
function GSN_add_custom_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
?>
<h3><?php _e('Altre Informazioni', 'GSN_textdomain'); ?></h3>
<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="tessera"><?php _e('Tessera FIDAL', 'GSN_textdomain'); ?>
            </label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="tessera" id="tessera" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'tessera', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e('Inserire il proprio numero tessera FIDAL: FE0.....', 'GSN_textdomain'); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="annonascita"><?php _e('Anno di nascita', 'GSN_textdomain'); ?>
            </label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="annonascita" id="annonascita" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'annonascita', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e('Inserire il proprio anno di nascita', 'GSN_textdomain'); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
<?php }
function GSN_save_custom_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return FALSE;
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'tessera', $_POST['tessera'] );
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'annonascita', $_POST['annonascita'] );
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'GSN_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'GSN_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'GSN_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'GSN_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
/*^^^^^^^^^^^^^*/
```